# python Beremiz.py no funciona correctamente

Tags: python, c, wxpython, wxwidgets

Tengo linux mint 20.3 (antes 20.2) en una netbook antigua. Estoy tratando de utilizar un programa open source "OpenPLC_Editor" que sirve para programar PLC. Está basado en un programa hecho en python "Beremiz.py" también de código abierto. No sé si es el lugar correcto para preguntar y saber si alguien me puede ayudar

[image: Esta es una de las vistas].

Hay una imagen de cada vista. Resumiendo, no funciona correctamente. Tiene dos vistas principales, una de texto y la otra gráfica. En la primera aparecen rectágulos con un número adentro dónde deberían haber carácteres, deduzco que representa el código ascii del caracter. En la gráfica deberían aparecer texto junto a los objetos (bloques), todo en general en inglés. Además otro problema que hay es que no se puede simular el PLC que es una de las funciones que tiene.

[image: Esta es la otra vista]

A veces aparece un error que lo guarda en un log., lo he enviado a los que desarrollaron Beremiz.py, pero no me han respondido. Si alguien puede ayudarme, desde ya muchas gracias.

Perdón por mi ignorancia, pero lo único que puedo agregar es lo que se muestra en la consola y el contenido de un archivo de texto generado, pienso que es por el error:

```
bash

jose@NetBook-LT25:~/OpenPLC_Editor$ l
editor/      LICENSE             README.md  update.cmd
get-pip.py   matiec/             Release/   update.sh*
install.sh*  openplc_editor.sh*  revision   wxpython/
jose@NetBook-LT25:~/OpenPLC_Editor$ ./openplc_editor.sh 

(Beremiz.py:43146): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 20:13:49.730: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed in GtkScrollbar

(Beremiz.py:43146): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 20:15:10.763: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed in GtkScrollbar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jose/OpenPLC_Editor/editor/controls/VariablePanel.py", line 150, in GetValue
    return _(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk3/wx/_gdi.py", line 3228, in GetTranslation
    return _gdi_.GetTranslation(*args)
PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "Assert failure" failed at ../src/common/wincmn.cpp(3346) in DoNotifyWindowAboutCaptureLost(): window that captured the mouse didn't process wxEVT_MOUSE_CAPTURE_LOST

(Beremiz.py:43146): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 20:17:20.240: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed in GtkScrollbar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jose/OpenPLC_Editor/editor/controls/VariablePanel.py", line 150, in GetValue
    return _(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk3/wx/_gdi.py", line 3228, in GetTranslation
    return _gdi_.GetTranslation(*args)
PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "Assert failure" failed at ../src/common/wincmn.cpp(3346) in DoNotifyWindowAboutCaptureLost(): window that captured the mouse didn't process wxEVT_MOUSE_CAPTURE_LOST
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jose/OpenPLC_Editor/editor/controls/VariablePanel.py", line 150, in GetValue
    return _(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk3/wx/_gdi.py", line 3228, in GetTranslation
    return _gdi_.GetTranslation(*args)
PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "Assert failure" failed at ../src/common/wincmn.cpp(3346) in DoNotifyWindowAboutCaptureLost(): window that captured the mouse didn't process wxEVT_MOUSE_CAPTURE_LOST
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jose/OpenPLC_Editor/editor/controls/VariablePanel.py", line 150, in GetValue
    return _(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk3/wx/_gdi.py", line 3228, in GetTranslation
    return _gdi_.GetTranslation(*args)
PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "Assert failure" failed at ../src/common/wincmn.cpp(3346) in DoNotifyWindowAboutCaptureLost(): window that captured the mouse didn't process wxEVT_MOUSE_CAPTURE_LOST
```

Esto es lo se ve en la salida mientras trato de crear un nuevo proyecto. Dentro del programa deberían mostrarse los elementos (los que se ven en la primera imagen, que son de un proyecto ya hecho que tenía con una versión anterior) con sus textos (en la imagen solo aparecen los elementos, pero no los textos) y no se ve nada.
Lo otro que puedo publicar es archivo que se genera mientras trato de hacer algo en el programa.

file:///tmp/beremiz/bug_report_2022_05_17__20-17-20.txt

```
app-title:
beremiz

app-version:
1.3.3
Release: 2022-05-16

cwd:
/home/jose/OpenPLC_Editor

date:
Tue May 17 20:17:20 2022

e-type:
<class 'wx._core.PyAssertionError'>

e-value:
C++ assertion "Assert failure" failed at ../src/common/wincmn.cpp(3346) in DoNotifyWindowAboutCaptureLost(): window that captured the mouse didn't process wxEVT_MOUSE_CAPTURE_LOST

locals:
    args: ('Local',)

platform:
Linux-5.4.0-110-generic-x86_64-with-LinuxMint-20.3-una

python-version:
2.7.18

traceback:
  File "/home/jose/OpenPLC_Editor/editor/controls/VariablePanel.py", line 150, in GetValue
    return _(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk3/wx/_gdi.py", line 3228, in GetTranslation
    return _gdi_.GetTranslation(*args)
<class 'wx._core.PyAssertionError'>: C++ assertion "Assert failure" failed at ../src/common/wincmn.cpp(3346) in DoNotifyWindowAboutCaptureLost(): window that captured the mouse didn't process wxEVT_MOUSE_CAPTURE_LOST

wx-platform:
__WXGTK__

wx-version:
3.0.2.0
```

No encuentro otra cosa para mostrar.

---

Esta la nueva muestra del programa.

[image: Ahora se el texto y se puede simular]

Comment: Podrías publicar el error que a veces aparece por favor? Quizá interpretando eso se pueda saber de donde proviene el error y su causa.

Comment: Por favor envie un [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (ver [code of a wxPython application](https://pastebin.com/pn86mFiK))

Comment: No sé la causa del fallo (aunque si la parte que la provoca). Lo que me llama la atención es que parece usar Python 2.7 (muy antiguo, ya no está soportado). El problema no viene de beremiz.

Comment: Logré hacerlo funcionar. Tomé los fuentes de beremiz y compilé un módulo que se llama matiec, que la base de las normas de programación y escribí sobre los que ya estaban y anduvo, da errores, pero no afecta el funcionamiento. Digamos que ahora estoy trabajando sobre beremiz y sobre openplc_editor. Después veré si esto logro cambiarlo.